# Deciding architecture for Api with common challenge authentication scheme

Tags: asp.net-core, architecture, multi-tenant

We are creating an exposing Apis to multiple clients for integration purposes. The main idea is the challenge scheme should be same to authenticate and issue token and a redirect Url.

I am thinking of two options

**Option 1: Plugin based architecture:** Create a single api that will load specific plugins. Each client requirement is implemented in class library and load the desired plugin based on request. Like a request is made by client A. client A plugin to be loaded and then this will handle the request.

**Option 2: Separate Api for each client:** Each client requirement is implemented in a separate Api. The authentication scheme is same to provide and redirect to this url.

What is best way to handle this?

Comment: In my opinion, the Plugin based architecture will be good, all the client just need use same api's token. There is no need to put it for separate api.

Comment: How many clients do you have now? How many do you expect to have in the near future (lets say 1 year later)?

Comment: @PeterCsala Expected 50 plus

Comment: Maintaining 50+ endpoints/plugins seems to be a really tedious and error-prone task. Can't you introduce groups to lower this number?